# Google sheets Average function is not calculating correctly

Tags: google-sheets, filter, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm using Google Sheets to create a financial record.

What i'm trying to do is create a formula that takes 3 columns in my data range in to consideration. The three columns are a date, a word and a number.

The first part of the formula will check that the date is the current month (not within 30 days, but the current month). The second part will check whether the word "Yes" is present in the second column, and if those two are true, then it will take the average of column 3 for all other rows that are also completely true.

Column C is Date
Column W is Word
Column Y is Number

I've tried a number of methods, the first one was to use a average IF function, where i used a filter to check the dates, and then the word Yes in the criterion. This resulted in a number, although it was incorrect, as the formula first gathered the sequence of Yes and No's, once it had the sequence it applied it to the third column but it started from my earliest entry (not my current month). This code is below.

So alternatively i tried another method. Which was using a query function. Although i'm stuck on how to compare the month of a date to the current today() month. This gives no results, even though the current month is 8, and the dates month is also 8.  I've also inputted this code below.

```
=AVERAGEIF(filter(W8:W800,month(C8:C800)=month(today())),"Yes",Y8:Y800)

=query(query(A8:Z800,"select month(C)+1, W, Y where W ='Yes'",0),"select Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1 ='"&month(today())&"'",1)
```

results explained in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have multiple criterions you need to use `AVERAGEIFS` instead of `AVERAGEIF`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGEIFS(C2:C, B2:B, "yes", MONTH(A2:A), MONTH(TODAY())))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Oh you beauty, i did try averageifs as well, but my train of thought was so short (was quite late at night), that i couldn't string it together and thought "nah this can't be the way".

Answer (score 1):

Your nesting is a bit off. If you're using `FILTER`, use plain `AVERAGE` instead of `AVERAGEIF`, and make sure you're grabbing the right column to aggregate. Lastly, don't forget to wrap in `IFERROR` to handle your empty case.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(FILTER(Y8:Y800, MONTH(C8:C800)=MONTH(TODAY()), W8:W800="Yes")), 0)
```

Comment: i need to wrap my mind around iferror's role it plays but this works perfectly. Thank you Kate :)

Comment: @bart.s `IFERROR` returns the result of the 1st parameter, except if that result is an error. If it is, it returns the 2nd parameter instead (in this case, 0).